# Remove items from conextual menu?

Tags: google-chrome, preview, search, services

I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google) thread to make my own "Search with Chrome" Service. But when i right click some highlighted text in Preview.app it lists both "Search with Google" and "Search with Chrome."

"Search with Google" is the second item in the contexual item list so it doesn't seem like a service (since its not at the bottom) and it always uses safari to search even though chrome is my default browser. There is a "Search with Google" item in Services that is separate from my "Search with Chrome" service that i made. The "Search with Google" service is unchecked though so it shouldnt show up.

How do i remove this "Search with Google" item so that i only see "Search with Chrome" when i right click highlighted text in preview?

Here are some screenshots

Mysterious "Search with Google"

[image: Mysterious "Search with Google"]

Context menu in Preview.app

[image: Context menu in Preview.app]

Answer (score 1):

The default "Search with Google" should be listed in the Keyboard Shortcuts under the Services tab.

You can un-check it and it shouldn't show up in the menu (This doesn't delete it however, just hides it from the menu).[image]

Comment: you can see from the pictures in my post that i have it unchecked already.... it isn't going away.